# Google Cloud DL Container deployed to GCE with GPU can't find CUDA Device

Tags: google-compute-engine, nvidia-docker

I use Pytorch image for GPUs: gcr.io/deeplearning-platform-release/pytorch-gpu.1-2:latest. I deploy it to GCE with K80 and V100 GPUs.

```
import torch
torch.cuda.device_count()
#returns 0
```

Cuda is installed. When I ssh into docker container and run following command on terminal, I can see it.

```
cat /usr/local/cuda/version.txt
CUDA Version 10.0.130
```

FYI, nvidia-smi command from terminal does not work. What am I doing wrong? Or is there a problem with docker images?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the NVIDIA driver has not been installed correctly. Please note that “[each version of CUDA requires a minimum GPU driver version or a later version.](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/add-gpus#install-gpu-driver)” To check the minimum driver required for your version of CUDA, see this link: [Toolkit and Compatible Driver Versions](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/cuda-compatibility/index.html#binary-compatibility__table-toolkit-driver).

You can follow this [link to install the driver manually](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/add-gpus#install-gpu-driver). Also you can find some [libraries that needs to be installed in this link](https://towardsdatascience.com/troubleshooting-gcp-cuda-nvidia-docker-and-keeping-it-running-d5c8b34b6a4c).